# Add specific text/tag after every few lines in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, awk, text

I have a text file where I have to add tags (in the form of normal text) to a .txt file.

For example, suppose I have a text file like this:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

I want to add the tags `<hello>` and `</hello>` before and after every 3 rows, respectively, and make it look somewhat like this:

```
<hello>
 a
 b
 c
</hello>
<hello>
 d
 e
 f
</hello>
<hello>
 g
 h
</hello>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your last entry only has 2 lines - is it necessary to handle that special case, or do you need to handle only the 3-line case?

Comment: @steeldriver Need to handle the special case too.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
$ sed -e '1~3i<hello>' -e '3~3{$!a</hello>' -e'}' -e '$a</hello>' a.txt
<hello>
a
b
c
</hello>
<hello>
d
e
f
</hello>
<hello>
g
h
</hello>
```

Explanation:

- `1~3i<hello>` insert `<hello>` every third line, starting at line 1
- `3~3a</hello>` append `</hello>` every third line, starting at line 3 but excluding the last line of the file `$`
- at the last line `$`, add the closing tag regardless of line number

---

If the file contains an exact multiple of 3 lines then it's simpler - just

```
sed -e '1~3i<hello>' -e '3~3a</hello>' a.txt
```

Comment: This works like a charm. But if the last bunch of sentences( group of 3) are not present it adds a extra closing tag.
Two </hello> </hello>

Comment: @ShrinidhiKulkarni please try the revised version above

Comment: Works perfect!!

Comment: is there a way to avoid the last tag if not for special case?

Comment: @ShrinidhiKulkarni yes if the file is an exact multiple of 3 lines you can just do `sed -e '1~3i<hello>' -e '3~3a</hello>'`

Comment: Sorry to put question in wrong way. What if you are not sure if it is 2 lines or 3 lines(any number of lines) how do you handle that condition.